# Link against a **custom** asan library

Tags: clang, llvm, clang++, address-sanitizer

What is the right way of using a custom (built by me from llvm sources) asan library?

During compilation I am using `-fsanitize=address`.

But what should I use for linking? It is recommended everywhere to use `-static-libasan` or `-shared-libasan`, but as far as I understand, linker will use the library that comes with compiler (not mine).

Shall I drop `-static-libasan` / `-shared-libasan` and just link against the `clang_rt.asan-dynamic-x86_64` built by me? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

if you use `-shared-libasan` at build time it will link to the shared lib which is what you want, and it will default to that standard path, but you should be able to easily override it when you go to run your app to use your own build using LD_PRELOAD.
for example:
`LD_PRELOAD=/home/yourname/llvm/lib/clang_rt.asan...so myapp`
so...the linker won't load the standard one because yours will be loaded into memory already and myapp will link up to it.
you still might need to make sure the version you are building from source is the same or close enough to the one that it linked to myapp at build time.